# Classes/Methods with Rectangle

Tags: python-3.x

So after working out some of the basics and playing around I'm finally starting to get used to Python, at least in a basic sense.  Thank you to those who have been so nice in helping me around here.

I am however hung up on an exercise I seen in a book, which is written as follows.

Create a class named 'Rectangle' with the following attributes and methods (sample run for each method included):

1) Each instance should have an x, y, width, and height attributes.

2) You should be able to pass the attributes when creating the rectangle as follows, (where x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100 in that order):

```
    r = Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
```

3) Create a method that returns the rectangle as a string (hint: implement **str** ). For a rectangle object with attribute values x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100, it should return the string “Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)”.

```
r2 = Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
print(r2)
  Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
```

4) Create a method called `right` that gets the value of the right edge of the rectangle. It should take no arguments:

```
r3 = Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20)
 r3.right()
  13     

r4 = Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35)
 r4.right()
  84
```

5) Create a method called `bottom` that gets the value of the bottom edge of the rectangle.

```
r5 = Rectangle(5, 7, 10, 6)
r5.bottom()
  13      

r5.y += 12    
r5.bottom()
  25
```

6)  Create a method called `size` that returns the width and height of your rectangle.

```
r6 = Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4)
r6.size()
  (3, 4)
```

7) Create a method called `position` that returns the x and y coordinates of your rectangle.

```
r6.position()
  (1, 2)
```

8) Create a method called `area` that returns the area of your rectangle.

```
r6.area()
  12
```

9) Create a method called `expand` that takes an offset value and returns a copy of the rectangle expanded with offset in all directions.

```
r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
r    
  Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)

r1 = r.expand(offset=3) 
r1    
  Rectangle(27, 37, 106, 116)
```

The original rectangle should not be modified.

```
r
  Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)
```

Negative values should return a shrunken rectangle.

```
r.expand(-5)
  Rectangle(35, 45, 90, 100)
```

So far here is where I am:

```
    class Rectangle:

        def __init__(self, X, Y, W, H):

        self.x = X

        self.y = Y

        self.w = W

        self.h = H
        x=5
        Y=10
        W=50
        H=100

def complete(self):
    return self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h

def right(self):
    return self.x + self.w

def __str__(self):
    return('Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ','
                    + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')')
def bottom(self):
    return self.y + self.h

def __str__(self):
    return('Rectangle(' + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.h) + ','
                    + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.h) + ')')
def size(self):
    return self.w,self.h

def position(self):
    return self.x,self.y

def area(self):
    return self.w * self.h

def expand(self):
    ''

print(Rectangle(5,10,50,100).complete())

print(Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20).right())

print(Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35).right())

print(Rectangle(5,7,10,6).bottom())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).size())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).position())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).area())
```

the second part of the exercise I have not attempted yet as I am still working on the first part.

Create a method called `contains_point` that takes coordinates x and y as parameters and returns True if the point in inside (or on the edge) of the rectangle and False otherwise.

```
r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110) 

r.contains_point(50, 50)
  True  

r.contains_point(30,40)
  True

r.contains_point(130, 150)
  True      

r.contains_point(131, 50)
  False      

r.contains_point(0,0)
  False
```

so basically I'm just working on the first part of the question at this point and looking for some input on what I have so far.  I'm still hung up on section 1 question 9 and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong with my code in general.  Suggestive reading, criticism whether critical or constructive are all appreciated

Comment: This question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If my code were working properly I would have gone through code review, however I cant seem to get anything to link up properly which is why I posted here

Comment: I recommend splitting this question in 2. Take the part(s) that work and put them on code Review. Take the thing which isn't working and make a specific question about it.

Comment: You never said what precisely is wrong or not working in your code. It is only question 9, you need to remove all the cruft that is questions 1-8: I don't think that is necessary, and just distracts. Then, you should give some expected output and show what you actually get. Preferably with a minimal working example.

Comment: I figured this out thanks for the support everyone.  I was just making this more difficult than it needed to be